# React native expection java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/{package}/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit

Tags: android, java-native-interface, react-native, .so

I am trying to integrate React Native with my existing Android App. I am getting the following exception, when initilizing React Native Screen:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: 
>   "/data/data/com.snapdeal.main/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit
>   instead of 64-bit

*The App is only crashing on 64-bit devices.*

As per my learning so far, I've found this [issue](https://github.com/oney/react-native-webrtc/issues/121) reported on React Native Repo, but the [solution](https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet-react/commit/30a9ca40750f6a01a5eae0f8fa5c428ce541b147) suggested in this thread is not helpful as I am not using any external SO library in existing App.

Apart from above, I've realized another difference in library structure on the device where my App is installed. I am comparing structure of my App vs react native demo app.

**React demo App**

```
root@generic_x86_64:**/data/data/com.react.demo/lib** # ls
libfb.so
libfolly_json.so
libglog.so
libglog_init.so
libgnustl_shared.so
libicu_common.so
libimagepipeline.so
libjsc.so
libreactnativejni.so
libreactnativejnifb.so

root@generic_x86_64:/data/data/**com.react.demo**/lib-main # ls
dso_deps
dso_lock
dso_manifest
dso_state
```

**My App**

```
root@generic_x86_64:/data/data/**com.my.app**/lib-main # ls
dso_deps
dso_lock
dso_manifest
dso_state
libfb.so
libfolly_json.so
libglog.so
libglog_init.so
libgnustl_shared.so
libicu_common.so
libimagepipeline.so
libjsc.so
libreactnativejni.so
libreactnativejnifb.so
```

Sharing few more details about my project:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "projectname",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Native NPM",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "author": "Ishan D",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-native": "^0.37.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^1.5.15",
    "rn-viewpager": "^1.1.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

**dependencies used in android native project**

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 24
    buildToolsVersion = '24.0.2'
    minSdkVersion = 16
    targetSdkVersion = 24
    supportLibrariesVersion = '23.0.1'
    playServiceVersion = '9.0.2'

    dep = [
            fabricPlugin          : 'io.fabric',
            fabricMavenUrl        : 'https://maven.fabric.io/public',
            fabricClasspath       : 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+',

            playServiceClasspath  : 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1',
            playServicePlugin     : 'com.google.gms.google-services',

            playServiceAppindexing: "com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:$playServiceVersion",
            playServiceLocation   : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServiceVersion",
            playServiceVision     : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:$playServiceVersion",
            playServiceAuth       : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:$playServiceVersion",
            playServiceBase       : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:$playServiceVersion",
            playServiceIdentity   : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:$playServiceVersion",
            playServiceAnalytics  : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:$playServiceVersion",
            playServiceGcm        : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServiceVersion",

            underCouchClasspath   : 'de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:2.0.0',
            underCouchPluigin     : 'de.undercouch.download',

            crashlytics           : 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.4.0@aar',

            moengage              : 'com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:6.0.29',

            supportV4             : "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportLibrariesVersion",
            supportAppCompatV7    : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibrariesVersion",
            supportCardviewV7     : "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibrariesVersion",
            supportDesignV7       : "com.android.support:design:$supportLibrariesVersion",

            okhttp                : 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0',
            junit                 : 'junit:junit:4.12',
            mockito               : 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    ]
}
```

Any clue is appreciated.

PS: I know react-native does support 64-bit binaries and I am not using any external library.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add the following into app/gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
....

    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
    }
}
```

also make sure you working with the same port.

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Comment: Also see this issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11027

Comment: also add "armeabi" in  abiFilters, without that the it doesnt . work on certain phones like samsung s7 ,  facebook should  do a better . job of adding all the filters . one needs to add to ensure this works on all devices.

Answer (score 12):

It can also help you:
build.gradle (app)

```
android{
   ...
   defaultConfig {
      ....
      ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
      }
      packagingOptions {
               exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
               exclude '/lib/mips64/**'
               exclude '/lib/arm64-v8a/**'
               exclude '/lib/x86_64/**'
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Does deploying APK with this build.gradle support 64 bit for google play store?

Comment: No google will not allow as 64 bit also you can check Build -> Analyse Apk

Answer (score 2):

*React Native doesn't provide 64-bit version of the native code and the system always fall back to 32-bit.*
They have resolved this issue and is scheduled to be part of the `RN 0.59 release`
Ref: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814#issuecomment-457644191

Answer (score 1):

```
Using RN 0.60.5 version.
If you guys are wondering why your app crashes if you download it from playstore, make the below changes

**packagingOptions {
exclude '/lib/mips64/'
exclude '/lib/arm64-v8a/'
exclude '/lib/x86_64/**'
//In pickFirst, replace the library name with the library that is causing error.
pickFirst '/lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so' 
pickFirst '/lib/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_shared.so'
}**

REASON - We are excluding all 64 bit libraries so that OS will not have confusion of which library to pick.

If you do not know which library is causing the crash, upload your bundle in Firebase test lab and then check. It will tell you which library is throwing the error
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer