# .so file is 64-bit instead of 32-bit - Android Studio, Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-library

I have a .so file inside of the jiniLibs folder . . . it includes the following folders:

**"armeabi",**

**"arm64-v8a",**

**"armeabi-v7a",**

**"x86",**

**"x86_64"**

. . . the Gradle code:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 30
buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    ndk {
         // i tried to write  abiFilters "armeabi", "arm64-v8a" , "armeabi-v7a" ,"x86", "x86_64" and did not work 
         abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

I always get this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/xxx.xxx.xxx-xxx-xxx==/lib/arm/xxx.so" is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
```

Edit:

I changed the gradle code to

```
    ndk {
         abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86" , "arm64-v8a"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/xxxxxxx.so"
    }
```

but i get this error now

```
.so is 64-bit instead of 32-bit
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694285/react-native-expection-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen-failed-data-dat Hope this answers the question

Comment: the error is so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit now

Comment: see the edit for more details